# SQL statement to compare Values in different rows/columns

Tags: sql

```
USER            ValidFrom               ValidTo
A1               1-Feb-20               3-Feb-20
A1               5-Feb-20               7-Feb-20
A1               8-Feb-20               11-Feb-20
B1               2-Feb-20               3-Feb-20
B1               6-Feb-20               9-Feb-20
```

I need to write a select statement to retrieve ONLY one record for each USER with lowest `validFrom`, and highest `validTo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `GROUP BY` statement.

```
SELECT USER, MIN(validFrom), MAX(ValidTo) FROM table GROUP BY USER;
```

Comment: _and highest validTo_, did you forget?

Comment: Now thats what you need?